# pymongo: possible to iterate result use next() and prev()?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I have a database with a column "id", integer type. I am using:

records = config.gSupei1Collection.find().sort([("id",pymongo.DESCENDING)])

To get the cursor, and then I use

record = records[0]

to get the largest ID record.

I am wondering after I got 'record', can I use record.next(), record.prev() to get the record that is neighbour to the record? I can't find any document.

Comment: What happens if you try it? Have you also tried `next(records)`?

Comment: what does next(records) mean?

Comment: If `records` is an iterator, then `next(records)`...gets the next thing from it. Or if you want the first two, you can do records[0] and records[1]...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop the records. Record is an actual document (a dict), not an iterator, but the result is.

You can do something like this:

```
for i, d in enumerate(records):
    print i, d
```

Or if you want to use the returned records as an iterator, you can do something like:

```
n = records.next()
```

Or for forward compatibility:

```
n = next(records)
```

Records is an iterator. Every time you see something that you can loop, it's an iterable, and you can just call `next()` and `rewind()` on it. Be careful though, calling `rewind()` will reissue the same query to the database server.

FYI, the easiest way to see what type something is is to prototype your program in the interpreter, then you can do `>> help(records)` and see the pydocs.

Comment: Thanks, but I can't afford to iterate like this.

Comment: What do you mean? Records is an iterator.

Comment: For performance issue, I can't iterate all the record. I only want to get the next() and prev() record in the record set. So pymongo can't do this easily?

Comment: `next(records)` is preferred over `records.next()` for recent versions of Python, because it works with no change on Python 3.

Comment: You don't have to iterate all the records. I think the iterator returns a document on demand, and when you do for in, it is invoked automatically.